# While Loop for Adventure Game IN Python

Tags: python

I am following the instructions from this lab: http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=lab_adventure&lang=en

I am confused on how to allow the user to proceed to other rooms after setting up these if statements. I followed the instructions but I might be incorrect.
Here is my code so far:

```
room_list=[]

room = ["You are in a small bedroom! There is a door to the north.", 1, None, None, None]
room_list.append(room)
room = ["You are now in a bigger bedroom! There is a door to the East!", None, 2, None, None]
room_list.append(room)
room = [ "You are now in the North hall! There is a Door to the South!", None, None, 3, None]
room_list.append(room)
room = [" You are now in the South hall! There is a door to the East!", None, 4, None, None]
room_list.append(room)
room = [" You are now in the dining room but you smell something past the North door!", 5, None, None, None]
room_list.append(room)

current_room = 0


done = False
while not done:
   print(room_list[current_room][0])
   user_c = input("What direction do you want to go?")
   if user_c.lower() == "north":
      next_room = room_list[current_room][1]
      current_room = next_room
   elif user_c.lower() == "east":
      user_c = room_list[current_room][2]
   elif user_c.lower() == "south":
      user_c = room_list[current_room][3]
   elif user_c.lower() == "west":
      user_c = room_list[current_room][4]
   else:
      print("I dont understand.")
   if user_c == None :
      print("You can't go that way.")
```

Once the user has gone to the North room how do I proceed to the East room without conflicting with the other if statements?..
Apologize for the dumb question and thank you for your help!

Comment: Please fix the indentation

Comment: have you thought of a two.dimensional array? it would give you room-setting a spacial 'correctness'. start at `rooms[0][0]` -> north -> `rooms[1][0]` -> east `rooms[1][1]` and so on

Comment: Also, you don't have to declare a new variable to append it to the list. For example, `room_list.append(["You are in a small bedroom! There is a door to the north.", 1, None, None, None])`

Comment: I think all you need is to duplicate the line `current_room = next_room` in other elif parts. Do this and try again. Tell me if this what you are looking for.

Comment: I used the Elif parts to set the user_c to None if the user went an other direction other than North. How do I direct the user through the rooms without conflicting the if statements?.. I tried nesting an If statement after the  initial if statement but that wouldn't work.. If I make another if statement for East it calls the elif "east" statement instead.

Comment: Part of your problem is your choice of data structures. Consider using a list of `dict`s. it will simplify things greatly

Comment: Also, man, that is a really awful tutorial. It might have some merit for teaching *beginners* Python, but it's not at all what you'd want to do if you were actually developing in Python. While there really is a lot of great content on the web to learn Python, there's also a lot of garbage. Acknowledge that there is no best way to do things, but simultaneously try to follow best practices as much as possible. That usually consists of consulting with the Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try using really simple classes and dictionaries. They're essentially what you're looking for.

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, text, other_rooms=None):
        self.text = text
        self.other_rooms = other_rooms

    def set_other_rooms(self, other_rooms):
        self.other_rooms = other_rooms

rooms = [Room("You are in a small bedroom! There is a door to the north."),
         Room("You are now in a bigger bedroom! There is a door to the East!"),
         Room("You are now in the North hall! There is a Door to the South!"),
         Room("You are now in the South hall! There is a door to the East!"),
         Room("You are now in the dining room. You smell something past the North door!"),]

rooms[0].set_other_rooms( { "north":rooms[1],
                            "south":None,
                            "east":None,
                            "west":None } )

rooms[1].set_other_rooms( { "north":None,
                            "south":None,
                            "east":rooms[2],
                            "west":None } )

rooms[2].set_other_rooms( { "north":None,
                            "south":rooms[3],
                            "east":None,
                            "west":None } )

rooms[3].set_other_rooms( { "north":None,
                            "south":None,
                            "east":rooms[4],
                            "west":None } )

rooms[4].set_other_rooms( { "north":rooms[5],
                            "south":None,
                            "east":None,
                            "west":None } )

current_room = None
done = False

while not done:
    print(current_room.text)
    user_c = input("What direction do you want to go?").lower()
    if user_c == "exit":
        done = True
    elif current_room.other_rooms[ user_c ]:
        current_room = current_room.other_rooms[ user_c ]
    else:
        print("You can't go that way.")
```

Also, man, that is a really awful tutorial. It might have some merit for teaching *beginners* Python, but it's not at all what you'd want to do if you were actually developing in Python. While there really is a lot of great content on the web to learn Python, there's also a lot of garbage. Acknowledge that there is no best way to do things, but simultaneously try to follow best practices as much as possible. That usually consists of consulting with the Stack Exchange.

Comment: @moxormog The Stack Exchange is definitely a great resource. I highly recommend reading other people's Python code. Now, I know it's kind of hard to determine what's good code and what's bad if you've never seen a concept implemented before. A nice remedy to this is gain a really strong understanding of the fundamentals of a language right away. You can do this by reading the top answers to StackOverflow posts with the `Python` tag. Also, reading the Python About/History page will help you understand the general motivations for the Python programming language, as well as its overall design.